# ExecuteScalar isn't returning current row first column

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have an auto-incremented primary key column `ProductId` in my table. Here is my code where I inserting a product using a stored procedure - I want my inserted rows first column value which is nothing but `productId` but `ExecuteScalar`  always returns 0 - why ?

```
Command = new SqlCommand("spInsertProduct", Connection);
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Command.Parameters.AddRange(aSqlParameter);

Connection.Open();
Int32 productId = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: in your stored procedure are you returning id?

Comment: No just insert a product information .

Comment: So if the `spInsertProduct` stored proc does not return anything why do you expect `ExecuteScalar` to?

Comment: Either use `select scope_identity()` or the `output` clause in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddEmployeeReturnIDwithoutput]
      @FirstName varchar(50),
      @LastName varchar(50),
      @BirthDate datetime,
      @City varchar(50),
      @Country varchar(50),
      @id int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO  Employees (FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, City, Country)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @BirthDate, @City, @Country)

    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    RETURN @id
END
```

Logic to retrieve the data:

```
// Using Output parameter
String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "AddEmployeeReturnIDwithoutput";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text.Trim();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BirthDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtBirthDate.Text.Trim();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCity.Text.Trim();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCountry.Text.Trim();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;    

cmd.Connection = con;

try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ;
    string id = cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value.ToString() ;
    lblMessage.Text = "Record inserted successfully. ID = " +  id;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

This is how you supposed to do .. If you don't return anything from the stored procedure, you will not get any value